# Make Ubuntu Server accept RDP connections

Tags: networking, server, remote-desktop

I started a Linux box from Ubuntu server. I wanted a minimal system, and since I'm a web developer, it made sense to start from Ubuntu server. I install Xorg server and I use suckless' dwm to manage my windows. Now I want to connect to my linux box remotely using Windows Remote Desktop client as we can do with Ubuntu Desktop.

What should I install on the linux box to be able to connect to it using RDP and use the same (or almost) experience as if I'm sitting before my PC.

I tried Cygwin\X but it was very slow, and I prefer to use a native Windows RDP client.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are doing, you installed a server. Following that it has no UI, but then you say you installed an X server? Why not just install an normal Ubuntu then? But ok, why do you want to rdp to it, you want to manage it via it's GUI? Not sure if there is something that supports the RDP protocol towards ubuntu. You can however use the rdp protocol to access windows machines from ubuntu. You could try out a VNC server and connect via that.

Comment: I don't want the full desktop package. I installed [dwm](http://dwm.suckless.org/) on Ubuntu. So this is a graphical interface that I want to connect to.